# Completely unrelated error using coredata

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, core-data

bridging header '/Users/bobby/Desktop/Project/Project_Name/Project_Name-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist

I am getting this error, trying to use core data to save data in my iphone app. It Shows up even when I put in a bridging header, though I shouldn't need to because it's on swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Go to targets -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective C Bridging Header and Double click on it and do this:

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete any bridging header in Navigator
2. Delete any path in targets -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective C Bridging Header, it should look like this:

[image]