# Swift Use of undeclared type 'GGLInstanceIDDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Google Cloud Messaging into my iOS app.
But I keep getting the error

> Use of undeclared type 'GGLInstanceIDDelegate'

I have been following the instructions on Google's support pages but to no avail. My code looks like:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        var osV = String(getMajorSystemVersion())

        if osV == "7"
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert)
        }
        else if osV == "8"
        {
            // Register for remote notifications
            var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
            var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings( forTypes: types, categories: nil )
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings( settings )
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

/* All the line below are throwing a similar error */  //GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig())
//registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken, kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
//GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)

        return true
    }
```

I am getting in my class declaration:

```
@UIApplicationMain 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate {
```

Has anybody had success with this? I would appreciate any help. I think it has to do with the linking or something like that.

Comment: make sure you add a bridge header in SWIFT

Comment: @ Daniel under Supporting Files I have added BridgingHeader.h with content: #import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>
Exactly like the google demo project

Comment: great, try to clear derived data window->projects->delete (on derived data)

Comment: @Daniel Nope still same error, tried cleaning the project also..

Comment: my podfile looks like this:

pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
target 'Notifications' do

end

target 'HelloSwiftTests' do

end

Comment: are you getting error only on GGLInstanceIDDelegate or all GGL?

Comment: Definitely on All GGL..

Comment: so you didn't import project as you need to. if it is a framework make sure you added it on build settings

Comment: Do you add your bridging header this way in Build Settings? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217531/completely-unrelated-error-using-coredata/31217617#31217617

Comment: Neither of those ways worked.

Comment: It seemed to work i think it wasn't linked properly. @Dharmesh that worked but now I'm getting: Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'GGLInstanceIDDelegate'. Absolutely no support on Google..

Comment: Thanks guys everything worked when i implemented the missing func's all errors went away! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the Bridging Header in the Xcode Build Settings under "Swift Compiler Generation" -> "Objective-C Bridging Header" like this:

```
"$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/ObjCBridgingHeader.h"
```