# How do I get a view to display on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm having trouble getting a view to actually display. I declare a variable of type CKCalenderView (which is linked from the storyboard). I then try to display it once the application loads. However, I'm still getting stuck on the splash screen. I'm new to Swift and iOS so I'm probably missing something obvious, but any help would be appreciated!

```
   import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CKCalendarViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mainCalendar: CKCalendarView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainCalendar.delegate = self;
    mainCalendar.hidden = false;
    mainCalendar.bringSubviewToFront(mainCalendar);
    //self.view.addSubview(mainCalendar);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Did you define the initial view controller?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is defined as the initial view controller. That is indicated by the arrow on the storyboard, correct?

Comment: Press Cmd+7 in Xcode, this brings you to the "Breakpoint" lane. Have you defined any breakpoints here?

Comment: If it's linked to the storyboard, then you shouldn't have to do anything to get it to display. Are your constraints set up?

Comment: I don't have any breakpoints it appears.

Comment: @Caleb I added constraints, but its still getting stuck on the splash screen.

Comment: Could it be because I did not import my Calendar Kit correctly to the view controller? It's native to Objective C, so I had to create a bridging header. The code inside is:        <br/>    #import "CalendarKit.h"
#import "CKCalendarView.h"
#import "CKCalendarViewController.h"
#import "NSCalendarCategories.h"
#import "NSDate+Components.h"

Comment: I wonder how you have integrated a 3rd party component like CKCalendarView in your application as an iOS beginner... Which kind or project have you created? A single view application?

Comment: @Darko Yes, I created a single view project. I use cocoapods to install 3rd party components.

Comment: Have you added the bridging header correctly to the Xcode project settings? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31784281/2664531

Comment: How did you add the CKCalendarView with Interface Builder to the view controller? It's an @IBOutlet.

Comment: @Darko I created a view object and added inside the view controller. I then changed the object's class to CKCalenderView and dragged it from the interface. I believe my bridge heading is correct; to add it I created a objective c file in my project and then was prompted whether I wanted to add a bridge. Is there another step I have to take?

Comment: Can you pass the Splashscreen when you remove the CKCalenderView in Interface Builder? Just to test if the CKCalenderView is the problem. You then also have to comment out the CKCalenderView related code.

Comment: @Darko Yes, once the CKCalenderView code is removed, it passes the splash screen.

Comment: Ok, then please try to create the CKCalenderView in code and not in IB. Just remove the '@IBOutlet weak' and call mainCalendar = CKCalendarView()  in viewDidLoad. You also have to set the frame of mainCalendar afterwards and add it as a sub view with self.view.addSubview(mainCalendar). I assume that IB has a problem to create the CKCalendarView.

Comment: @Darko Wow, that seems to have done it! Appreciate the help! Last thing, how do I add constraints if I can't work in the interface builder?

Comment: Great. Programatic constraints are really hard in iOS. Try "SnapKit", it makes it much easier.

Comment: why did you uncomment view.addsubview()?