# swift pod update Google Messaging generates error Use of undeclared type

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I updated my project pods to get the latest version of Google Messaging, but now I'm getting multiple errors while building my project:

```
Use of undeclared type 'GGLInstanceIDDelegate'
Use of undeclared type 'GCMReceiverDelegate'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLContext'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLContext'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GCMConfig'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GCMService'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GCMPubSub'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLInstanceIDConfig'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLInstanceID'
Use of unresolved identifier 'kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption'
Use of unresolved identifier 'kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLInstanceID'
Use of unresolved identifier 'kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GCMService'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GCMService'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLInstanceID'Use of unresolved identifier 'kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM'
```

Here is the result of the `pod update` command:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using GGLInstanceID (1.2.1)
Installing Google 2.0.4 (was 2.0.4)
Using GoogleCloudMessaging (1.2.0)
Using GoogleIPhoneUtilities (1.2.1)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1)
Installing GoogleMaps 2.0.1 (was 1.13.2)
Installing GoogleMobileAds (7.8.0)
Using GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.1)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)
Using GoogleUtilities (1.3.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 10
total pods installed.
```

And here is the content of my podfile:

```
target 'myProject' do
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'

end
```

I tried to run `pod update` again but the result remains the same. Perhaps a modification on the API entry points is needed?

I don't know exactly what can I do, any help will be more than appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Google Messaging pods and then `pod install`?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783996/swift-use-of-undeclared-type-gglinstanceiddelegate), if you encountered **Use of undeclared type 'GGLInstanceIDDelegate'** error, make sure you add a bridge header in Build Settings.

> You have to set the Bridging Header in the Xcode Build Settings under
>   "Swift Compiler Generation" -> "Objective-C Bridging Header" like
>   this:
>
> ```
> "$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/ObjCBridgingHeader.h"
> ```

You can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39352069/5832311) in other SO post. It states that error **Use of unresolved identifier** usually occurs when your new class has a different Target(s) from the other one. It might have a testing target and the other doesn't. You have to include all of your classes in the testing target or none of them.

Check these related SO threads which might help:

- ["Use of undeclared type" in Swift, even though type is internal, and exists in same module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437891/use-of-undeclared-type-in-swift-even-though-type-is-internal-and-exists-in-s)

  > For me, I encountered this error when my test target did not have some swift files that my app build target had in compile sources. It was very confusing because the 'undeclared type' was being used in so many other places with no problem, and the error seemed vague. So solution there was of course to add the file containing the 'undeclared type' to the test target.
- [Completely unrelated error using coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217531/completely-unrelated-error-using-coredata/31217617#31217617)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason why I had those errors while updating my pods...

Google updated from GCM to Firebase and changed their API entry points, so I need to change everything to match Firebase new Cloud messaging implementation !